# Entity Framework DB First: How to make a field optional

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db-first

I have some data class generated from the DB:

```
[Table("appdb.apptable")]

public partial class apptable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Sum { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

How, I need to support different table in a generic way.
The table name the same, but it does not contain Comment field.
I need somehow to make the Comment property optional.

How can I make an existent DB field optional in Entity Framework?

Comment: You cant map the same type to multiple tables. If you have entities with common properties you *could* create an abstract type and inherit from it where needed.

Comment: `Comment` isn't a field but property and as string is by default optional.